# window.location.pathname for "/users/#something here"

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have paths such as `"/users/2"` or `"/users/4"` or `"/users/25"` etc and I need to setup an `if` statement such as:

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/users/?????") {};
```

that catches all of these paths.

Comment: You're looking for regex.

Comment: You have to use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and find match to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: If your path is only ever "/users/x" then you don't need to use Regex at all. A simple substr() will suffice as the value you need always starts at the same index into the string.

Comment: @allnodcoms there are other paths such as `/users/x/edit` or `users/x/destroy` but for what I am doing in my code will not effect those paths.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss - RegEx it is then... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if (pathname.startsWith('/users/')) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Read more about [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)  method.

Answer (score 1):

you could check the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) of `'/users/'`

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;

if (pathName.indexOf('/users/') === 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you have just "/users/", and nothing after the 2nd slash your condition would be not satisfied, I suggest something to ensure you have the id of the user (checking the length of the string to be greather than --> the position of the substring to search AND its length added, if it's so --> there must be something after it, which we suppose it's the id...) like this:

```
var p = window.location.pathname;
if(p.indexOf("/users/") > -1 && p.length > p.indexOf("/users/") + 7) {
            ...
}
```

...maybe you can also check if the id after the 2nd slash is a number if needed...